# Position an image within the div at its centre

Tags: css

I have a div with id `leftheader` and I want to position an image within the div at its centre. I am trying this css

```
#leftheader {
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    height: 140px;
    margin: auto;
}

#leftheader img {
   /*padding-left: 80px;*/
}
```

When I use `padding-left: 80px;`, I get the centre alignment of the image. But since I have used `%` in the width of `leftheader`, I  dont want to use `pixel values`. Can anyone suggest me a more generic css layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the text-align :center; your image should center itself in the div.

```
#leftheader {
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    height: 140px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yep, easiest and best solution. Any text that needs to be aligned any other way should be in another container anyway, ie p tags which can be set to align differently.